# How to display price format ( small cents)

Tags: ios, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I try to display a price with small cents : the cents must be smaller than the other digits like on the image bellow. I searched in NSNumberFormatter but didn't find the answer.
Do you have an idea ?

[image: Price]

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the link "Superscript cents in an attributed string"

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your string formatted, you could create an `NSMutableAttributedString` with it. Search the string for your '.' and get the `NSRange` of the substring after it. Once you have this range, do something like:

```
[attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10], NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @10} range:centsRange];
```

You'll want to make sure you choose a smaller font size than the rest of your text.